# Add ChildEntityIds field in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two entities:

```cs
class User
{
    [Column("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Blog> Blogs { get; set; } = new List<Blog>();
    public IEnumerable<string> BlogIds { get; set; } = new List<string>(); // <-- how to implement this?
}

class Blog
{
    [Column("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Column("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Author))]
    public string AuthorId { get; set; }

    public User Author { get; set; }
}
```

I could solve this loading blogs with user and then using a getter, but there should be some more elegant solution.

Comment: Looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/168269). What do you want with `BlogIds`?

Comment: Because sometimes there are too many Blogs too load (> 500) and it takes too many resources to iterate through them and get only ids. In TypeORM (in TypeScript), for example, there is a helper decorator for it called `@RelationId`, that loads ids only.

Comment: Well, you don't have to query all complete blogs of one user to get their Ids only. What about `contect.Blogs.Where(b => b.AuthorId == someValue).Select(b => b.Id)`.